# Outlook freezes, waiting to complete an OLE action, when sending from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel macro that filters a sheet (a basic order form), copies and emails a range using an Outlook object. This worked for several weeks and ran quickly.

Now filtering and copying works but when it gets to the email code Outlook locks up.

I get a popup from Excel saying

> waiting for Outlook to complete an OLE action.

I have to kill the Outlook process. I tried early and late bindings.

```vb
Sub EmailOrder()

    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim lastRow As String
    Dim filteredRow
    Dim emailApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim emailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim exportRange As Range
    Dim currentTime As String
    Dim currentUserEmailAddress As String

    answer = MsgBox("Click OK to send your order to the supply team", vbOKCancel)

    If answer = vbOK Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        currentTable = "$A$1:$E$" & lastRow
        'Filter out blanks
        Range(currentTable).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
            
        Set exportRange = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        'Only the visible cells in the selection
        Set exportRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
        'Setup outlook objects and mail
        Set emailApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set emailItem = emailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        Set outSession = emailItem.Session.CurrentUser
        currentUserEmailAddress = outSession.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
        currentTime = Now
        
        'Write email
        With emailItem
            .To = "redacted@gmail.com"
            .CC = currentUserEmailAddress
            .Subject = "Local Inventory Order " & currentTime
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(exportRange)
            .Send
        End With
            
        'Close objects
        Set emailApp = Nothing
        Set emailItem = Nothing
        
        MsgBox ("The order has been emailed to the supply team.")
    End If
End Sub
```

The RangetoHTML function is from [Ron de Bruin's](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) website.

Other users reported it working for several weeks then stopping.

Comment: Has any security pop up appeared in outlook advising of programatic access?  Try `emailApp.visible=true` to show the outlook

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I've seen the popup before but it could have been on client's computers. Outlook trust center setting is to notification for all macros. I tried `emailApp.visible=true` but there was no difference.

Comment: There won't be a difference, just you will see outlook so switch to outlook see if there is any message there.   Try just displaying the message rather than sending it too, so if that helps

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - it is a good idea to use `Display` instead of `Send` to avoid the security prompt, but the script above will trigger the prompt even before that as it accesses `emailItem.Session.CurrentUser`